# Ruby on Rails: Is it possible to statically enforce that an instance method can only be called on a `persisted?` and not `changed?` instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

In Rails you can do the following:

```
class FooBar < ApplicationRecord
  def baz
    unless persisted? && !changed?
      raise SomeError, "This FooBar must be persisted and unchanged."
    end

    # do something
  end
end
```

But I'd prefer to avoid running into runtime errors, and I'd rather not have to take the (very slight) performance hit of checking of the record is `persisted?` and not `changed?`.  Is there a way to statically enforce that an instance method can only be called on a `persisted?` and not `changed?` instance?

I looked into ActiveRecord::Dirty, but couldn't find anything like what I was looking for.

Comment: Well to avoid the error you can just change it to a `return` but this will be surprising to end users which usually means a bang (`!`). Regarding the "performance hits" there isn't really anything there as both are simple Boolean checks

Answer (score 2):

"Statically enforcing" isn't really something you do at all in Ruby. Its a weakly typed dynamic language so there are no compile time checks.

You should really just think more carefully about what kind of flow this method needs - if the method should just bail silently when its called with bad input you add a guard statement and return early.

```
class FooBar < ApplicationRecord
  def baz
    if !persisted? && changed?
      return # this will just return nil
    end
    # do something ...
  end
end
```

This does still require the caller to be aware that the method may not return the expected value and handle it so that your don't just get `NoMethod` errors.

If this method being called on a new record is an exceptional event and the programmer should be notified and be able to rescue the error you should raise an exception.

> But I'd prefer to avoid running into runtime errors

Exceptions don't equal runtime errors and the caller can rescue the exception. This isn't actually a good way to reason about how to build your code. Choose the correct control flow for the task and don't be afraid of exceptions.

> I'd rather not have to take the (very slight) performance hit of checking of the record is persisted? and not changed?

This is completely irrelevant. Both just check boolean attributes.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need error raising, just return from this method

You will not feel improvement in performance but I think it will be more readable if use separate positive conditions instead of `unless`, `&&` and `!`

```rb
class FooBar < ApplicationRecord
  def baz
    return if changed?
    return if new_record?

    # do something
  end
end
```

Keep in mind, `new_record?` is not the same as `!persisted?` because there is `destroyed?` state